# How to straighten and rearrange UV Islands? (hair cards)

Tags: uv

[image: UV islands in Blender]

This is picture is so you can see what I mean. Reds are the same, and greens are the same and I want reds to be an island and green to be a separate island.

In the tutorial linked below, you can see that after he finished the hair in ZBrush and he created the UV layout, he then imports it in Maya and creates islands out of the similar hair cards (Step 8 and 9).

How can this be done in Blender?

https://www.3dartistonline.com/news/2015/04/how-do-i-create-real-time-hair-for-games/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the images you posted, you don't want the reds and greens to be in one island each. The strands are still separate UV islands, you just want to rearrange them, right?

Comment: @metaphor_set yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method to straighten and rearrange UV islands in Blender is by using the free add-on [**TexTools by renderjs**](https://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/).

After you installed TexTools, you find a new tab in the UV/Image Editor.

[image: TexTools Tab in UV Image Editor]

### Step 1

In the first step, you want to rectify all the UV islands. Select one island, click the Rectify button then repeat the process for all the UV islands.

[image: rectify UV islands]

### Step 2

Once you've rectified all islands, enter Face Select mode, then select the similar ones and rearrange them vertically at the top edge.

[image: rearrange phase 1]

### Step 3

In the next step, chose one island as template and scale the edges of the others vertically. Do this by selecting the same edges on each island except in the template island, then press <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>.

Repeat this for all edges.

[image: move edges to same hight]

### Step 4

After that, turn on "Snap to Vertex", hit <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while moving the edges vertically, until they snap at the same height as the template edge.

Repeat this for all edges.

[image: move edges to the edge position of the template UV island]

### Step 5

Now, position the islands roughly into a vertical stack, switch to Face Select mode, then press the "Align left" button to arrange them horizontally on the left edge.

[image: arrange islands horizontally on the left edge]

### Step 6

After that, turn on "Snap to Vertex", hit <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while moving the right edges horizontally and move your mouse over the template  until they snap at the same width as the right template edge.

[image: snap right edges of the islands to right edge of template island]

### Step 8

Repeat Step 1 to 7 for the second island group, then rearrange them by using the method in Step 2.

[image: final result]

Comment: You truly save me here, i thought I wouldn't find an answer. This was the last part of the puzzle trying to make hair cards. You didn't explain how to overlap them but that is the easiest part of all, and even in the add-on I can see a overlap button. Thanks again for an amazing replay