# Asphalt with Road Lines

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to create a unique road cycles material with straight and curved road lines and other road markings, overlapping different textures.

What are some effective ways to achieve that?

Comment: I would suggest using uv textures to create lines on the straight road and then use a lattice modifier to make it curved

Comment: "What is the best way" questions are highly opinion based. For roads I suggest using a method described [in my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/138984/23985)