# Texture tiling in Blender 2.82

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've been facing this issue with the version of Blender 2.82. First of all I'm a new Blender user, so keep in mind that since my skills are still very low.
I've searched on internet about Texture tiling but all the solutions are for older Blender versions so the Shading configuration seems changed with the latest version.
My issue is I've created a 3rd footpath and I'm using a .bmp file to take the texture, but I don't want to use the entire image for that particular footpath (the .bmp file has different textures, so I want to choose one in particular) and I want to apply this specific texture in loop on my footpath. For this process I'm using the UV Editor. 
Here some image of the issue I have:

In red square the specific texture I want to apply:

[image: In red square the specific texture I want to apply]

Here is how Blender applies the texture I've selected through the UV Editor

[image: Here is how Blender applies the texture I've selected through the UV Editor]

How can I do in order to make the selected texture area repeat itself avoiding that "bluring" "distorted" effect?
Thanks

Comment: Hello :). For most tiling purposes [Poliigon's Uber Mapping node](https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc) works very well

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Unfortunatelly is not resolving my issue. Again seems Blender is considering the whole texture image and not the part of the texture I'm interested in (as attached on my previous image).

Comment: What you are looking for, is called a **trim sheet workflow**. You might get some useful information out of my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/138984/23985).

Comment: So what you are saying is, if I have a mono block of a huge cubic object where I want to apply a specific part of my texture image, in order to repeat that part without stretching it for all the lenght of the object I have to cut the object in tiny equals parts? There is no "simple" function that make that texture part selected to repeat itself on the face of the object?